# Trying to use py2exe, but python is not recognized

Tags: python, py2exe

I am following the the tutorial at http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial to figure out how to use py2exe. I get down to step 3 where you are supposed to run the command:

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

I do that and then I get this error:

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have python 2.4 installed on my machine. any idea's? I am sure it is something simple.

Comment: Please fix your title "getting py2exe to work" is not informative at all.  "Python not installed" is a much more informative title.

Comment: The title "Python not installed" would be portraying false information seeing that I have python 2.4 installed.

Comment: Please pay attention. "getting py2exe to work" is a TERRIBLE question title.  Please fix it.  Almost anything would be better.  You could create something worse, but I can't see how.  PLEASE update your question to have a title which OTHER PEOPLE might see, and then learn from.  "getting py2exe to work" is guaranteed to be ignored.  Your problem, and the answer you accepted, COULD help other people -- if only you would fix the title.  Please fix the title.  Please.

Comment: Because your question isn't specific to py2exe you should rename it to something about the error message, possibly just quoting the beginning of the error: 'python' is not recognized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python just isn't on your path.  If you indeed have Python 2.4, it should be `C:\Python24\python.exe` with the default installer.

Wherever the file is located, if you don't set Python's folder in your path, you will write the command as

```
C:\Python24\python.exe setup.py py2exe
```

(or whatever the correct path is).

Depending on how your installation was configured, you might be able to just do

```
setup.py py2exe
```

since Windows *might* automatically associate *.py files with Python.

You might want to also read ["Finding the Python Executable"](http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html#finding-the-python-executable) from the Python documentation.

Comment: Thanks. I new it was something simple.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add python to your system path. This is done differently on different OSs. [Instructions for most versions of Windows](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)
You need to add C:\Python24 or whereever python is on your computer.