# py2exe installation error: 'python' not recongised

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmd, py2exe

I am installing py2exe and there is an error when I run cmd, which is 
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command
What should I do?

Comment: I think python is not properly set up as your path varaible. please configure it accordingly.

Comment: Sorry I am quite dumb at computing... what do you mean in simple words?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4855685/6879949) please follow this link u ll find an answer.

Comment: Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2999447).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to use py2exe, but python is not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999427/trying-to-use-py2exe-but-python-is-not-recognized)